# Nested Hash from Two Arrays in Ruby + Sorting and Filtering by value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am new to Ruby and have been trying to figure this out for three days now using all resources and several S/E posts that I found, but to no avail yet!!
Can someone please help me??

I have two simple arrays, one with labels and the other with the corresponding values. These are sorted in parallel, so item 1 of array 1 maps to item 1 of array 2.

Let's say for example I have these two arrays:

```
labels = ["WinterLabel","SummerLabel","SpringLabel","FallLabel"]
values = [80,15,8,2]
```

What I need to do is
1) filter out any pair(s) whose value is above 20
2) sort from smallest to largest value
3) convert to a nested hash structure like the one below
-not sure if this is the right order of tasks, maybe first make it a hash, then manipulate the data?-

```
outputhash = { 
  "name" => {
    :label => "FallLabel",
    :value => 2 
  },
  "name2" => {
    :label => "SpringLabel",
    :value => 8 
  },
  "name3" => {
    :label => "SummerLabel",
    :value => 15     
  }
}
```

The specific names for name, name2, name3 do not matter to me, it can be a number starting from 1 or it can have the same name as the label.

Any help or advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See if the following works for you:

```
labels = ["WinterLabel","SummerLabel","SpringLabel","FallLabel"]
values = [80,15,8,2]
output_hash = labels.map.with_index do |l, i| 
      {label: l, value: values[i]}  
    end.reject do |h|
      h[:value] > 20
    end.sort_by do |h| 
      h[:value] 
    end.each.with_object({}).with_index do|(h, memo), i| 
      memo[i+1] = h 
    end
```

Suggestion, if you're ok with the key of the main hash being the label then maybe this works better for you:

```
{"FallLabel"=>2, "SpringLabel"=>8, "SummerLabel"=>15, "WinterLabel"=>80}
```

Then you can just do the following:

```
output_hash = labels.map.with_index{|l, i| [l, values[i]]}.reject{|arr| arr[1] > 20}.sort_by(&:last).to_h
```

Also I wouldn't recommend using hashes for holding order information

Comment: Great, this code worked to create the hash and sort it!!!! What change do I have to make to this to also have the "cutoff" function, so elements with values over a threshold will not make it into the new hash?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to avoid ending up in a situation like this, and instead use objects to store the data, this is after all an object oriented language. If you had instead stored the data in a class like:

```
# Forgive the poor class name...naming things is hard
class MyClass
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :label, :value

  def initialize(label, value)
    @label = label
    @value = value
  end

  # required method for Comparable
  def <=>(other)
    value <=> other.value
  end

  def to_h
    { label: label, value: value }
  end
end
```

then you can simply do (assume `labels` contains an array of `MyClass` objects that have the same data as above):

```
labels.
  select { |label| label.value < 20 }.
  sort.
  each_with_object({}) do |my_class, output_hash|
    output_hash[my_class.label] = my_class.to_h
  end
  # => {"FallLabel"=>{:label=>"FallLabel", :value=>2},
  #     "SpringLabel"=>{:label=>"SpringLabel", :value=>8},
  #     "SummerLabel"=>{:label=>"SummerLabel", :value=>15}}
```

If, it doesn't make sense to include [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html) in your class (or if it doesn't make sense to compare them by their values only), then you can replace that `sort` line with

```
sort_by(&:value).
```

to achieve the same result. If refactoring to a class is outside the bounds of what your allowed to do, you can [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) the data together and treat them as if the label and value were in the same array the whole time:

```
labels.zip(values)
# => [["WinterLabel", 80], ["SummerLabel", 15], ["SpringLabel", 8], ["FallLabel", 2]]
```

and then you can sort and collect the hashes similarly from there:

```
labels.zip(values).
  select { |_, value| value < 20 }. # _ is ruby's conventional 'unused variable', meaning I don't care about the first value (the label) in each array
  sort_by(&:last).
  each_with_object({}) do |(label, value), output_hash|
    output_hash[label] = { label: label, value: value }
  end
  # => {"FallLabel"=>{:label=>"FallLabel", :value=>2},
  #     "SpringLabel"=>{:label=>"SpringLabel", :value=>8},
  #     "SummerLabel"=>{:label=>"SummerLabel", :value=>15}}
```

Comment: Hi Simple Lime! Thanks a lot for the detailed response and the willingness to explain more about the context and best practices involved in what I am doing.

I tried to implement your "simple" version and initially got an error "undefined local variable or method `output_hash' for main:Object". I then tried to declare output_hash as a hash before the loop (inserting output_hash ={}) so I don't get the error any more, but the result is an empty hash. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Except having to add the line where `labels = [MyClass.new(...), ...]` for the first example; all of the code here can be copied and pasted and run as expected, are you sure there are no typos or having left anything out when you transcribed it?

Answer (score 0):

Check it

```
labels = ["WinterLabel","SummerLabel","SpringLabel","FallLabel"]
values = [80,15,8,2]
outputhash = {}
values.each_with_index do |d, i|
  next if d > 20
  outputhash["name#{i}"] ={ lable: labels[i], value: d }
end
outputhash = outputhash.sort_by{|a,b| b[:value] }
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for the answer your code was successful in creating the right hash structure, but the sorting function doesn't seem to work. It is strange because I saw the exact same proposal on another site and was hoping it would work..! http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

Comment: ```[["name3", {:lable=>"FallLabel", :value=>2}],
 ["name2", {:lable=>"SpringLabel", :value=>8}],
 ["name1", {:lable=>"SummerLabel", :value=>15}]]```
Sorting works correctly see the output